# How to updatecamera only once

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I'm working on a project with google maps and I want to update the camera and camera zoom to the location of the user but only once (when the app is running) why only once? because I want the user to be able to move and drag around the map without updating the camera every 5 or "n" seconds.

I get the users position in the method onLocationChanged() and then I update the camera, but this is updating the camera every 5 seconds (my interval) and i is not what I want. I just want to update it the first time when the map is opened.

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.d(TAG, "OnLocationChanged"+String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())
            + "longitude" + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    eraseMarkers();
    if (mMap != null) {
        LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newLatLng,CAMARA_ZOOM));
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: I have used Google Maps with Android before, and I don't understand your question.  When should the camera move/zoom happen and when should it not?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen the Google map is launched when the user opens an activity, so, when the user opens this activity it should senda the user to its current location with the update, just the first time, just like uber app... when you launch the app it sends you to your current location, but then you can just move trough the map without the camera being updated.

Comment: In the map on my app this is already the default behavior.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not in my case Tim, what i'm doing is click in the Google maps button to send me to my loc...

Comment: So you want to only allow this to happen once, is that right?  If so, why not just add some global state to the activity which keeps track of this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry, I Dont understand your answer. How can i tell the actitivity just to do it once? Thanks

Comment: Just store some boolean state that records whether the camera move has happened already.  And you may need to keep track of this state across, e.g., a rotation from portrait to landscape.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the thing is that i have the method update inside onLocChanged(); and every time the user changes its Loc the camera updates...

Comment: OK, just so we're clear here, you want the `mMap.moveCamera()` call to happen only _once_ for each time the activity loads?  Is that right?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen right. Only once when it loads... with the user's location